# jquery mobile function not returning value

Tags: sqlite, cordova, jquery-mobile, web-sql

I'm trying to run a check on a webdb running on a cordova/jQuery-mobile application:

This function will check whether the table exists in the DB and subsequently return a true or false. I have tried to change the return type from boolean to integer (0 and 1) but with no success.

```
function checkConfigTable(tablename) {
  db.transaction
  (
       function (tx)
       {
            tx.executeSql
            (
                'SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type="table" AND name=?',
                [tablename],
                function(tx,results)
                {
                    var len = results.rows.length;
                    if(len>0)
                    {
                            return true;
                    }
                    else {
                            return false;
                    }
                }, errorCB
            );
       },errorCB,successCB
   );   
}
```

I want to then call checkConfigTable from this other one just to alert the return value (only for test purposes at the moment) but I am always getting "undefined" as return value.

```
// Function to retrieve current login config
function getSavedLogin(configid) {
    var x = checkConfigTable("config");
    alert('table: ' + x);
}
```

If I substitute the return with an alert directly in checkConfigTable() the correct values are shown in the alert box.

Comment: you mean the x is undefined??  if so make the x a global variable (put outside the function)-- var x; -- x = checkConfigTable("config");

Comment: Yes x is undefined. I'll try and set it as global.

Comment: yeah i thought that might be the case -- can you just run this function by itself -- checkConfigTable("config") -- and return the result from that function -- return result -- try that

Comment: I've tried to tun it with a console.log(checkConfigTable("config") ) but it still returns undefined

Comment: no like this example here --- https://jsfiddle.net/mjzebzqa/

Comment: Same result. Undefined

Comment: seems to work ok here -- https://jsfiddle.net/4wprufjg/